# Check in which triangle of a square are the given coordinates

Tags: java, function

I have a square and divided it into 4 equal triangles.
The top-left corner has the coordinates (0,0) and the bottom-right corner (1,1)
and I've labeled them from 1-4.

This function describes the borders of the top triangle:

```
double y;
for (double x = 0; x <= 1; x += 0.1) {
    y = x;
    if (x > 0.5) {
        y = 1 - x;
    }
    System.out.println("x = " + x + " and y =" + y);
}
```

While x goes from 0 to 1 y goes from 0 to 0.5 to 0.
But now i need a function where i can enter the coordiantes and it returns the triangle in which these coordinates are currently in and i can't think of a good way to do this. Any suggestions on how to make such a function?

Here is a screen of the square:
https://pllx.eu/eHL1sc/9Cvfel4OLnwb8SdV

Comment: If x > y then the point is in 1 or 2 otherwise in 3 or 4. If x + y < 1 then the point is in 1 or 4 otherwise in 2 or 3. Combine these two checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If x > y, you are in area 1 or 2.
- If y > x, you are in area 3 or 4.
- If x + y < 1, you are in area 1 or 4.
- If x + y > 1, you are in area 2 or 3.

If you work through the combination of these, you can discover exactly which area you are in.